# How to create and configure multi websites in magento2.2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

I have created two websites like this.

[image]

Actually my website like this http://puppetkart.com/
[image]

When i opened my new website, I am getting website without CSS and Media files.

[image]

Comment: You want to add multiple domain to each website ?

Comment: yes ok i added multiple domain. after that I have following page

Comment: please see the updated question and following link:http://vizag.puppetkart.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Websites and it's relevant Store and StoreView from Admin > Stores > All Stores
2. Go to Stores > Configuration, Select website which you have created. Then Go to Web and change both **Base URLs & Base URLs (Secure)**

   For example : 
   e.g. Base URL: puppetkart.com (Main website url keep as it is)
   Base Link URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}vizag/

   Here, **ch** is a sub directory folder which needs to create under your magento root folder
3. Create a sub directory folder, then copy index.php & .htaccess from root
4. Open index.php replace everything with the code bellow:

   ```
   require realpath(__DIR__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
   $params = $_SERVER;
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'vizag'; 
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
   $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
   $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
   $bootstrap->run($app);
   ```

   **vizag** is a website code.

Comment: my base url is puppetkart.com

Comment: i want to implement different websites for different cites like vizag and hyderabad

Comment: @nukalasatish, Check once my updated answer

Comment: ok i will check now

Answer (score 0):

clear static contents by with below command:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
```

And do deploy static contents:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: is it run the entire command in putty"rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*"

Comment: you can run entire or in parts like :rm -rf var/di/* , rm -rf var/generation/* , rm -rf var/cache/*

Comment: where to run them? in root or subdomain ?

Comment: see the above updated pic. The result shows like that in putty

Comment: Run this command in your terminal php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I already run this command but no response